# Assigning values to struct

Tags: c++, struct

I'm trying to create a genetic algorithm and I'm stuck on assigning values to my fitness condition. This is my code (or at least the part that's relevant to the question):

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <random>
#include <string>

const int population_size = 10;
const int number_of_variables = 7;

struct one_individual
{
std::vector<std::vector<double>>individual;;
double evaluation = 0;
double fit = 0;
};


int main()
{
// Generate random number

std::random_device rd;
std::mt19937 rng(rd());    // random-number engine (Mersenne-Twister in this case)
std::uniform_real_distribution<double> dist(-10.0, 10.0);

// Create vector that holds vectors called individual and fill size it to the amount of individuals I want to have.

one_individual individual;

for (int i = 0; i < population_size; i++)
{

    std::vector<double>variables;

    for (int j = 0; j < number_of_variables; j++)
    {
        variables.push_back(dist(rng));
    }

    individual.individual.push_back(variables);
    individual.fit = 0;
    individual.evaluation = 0;
}

// Do calculation with population. At the moment I just add up all the genes (sum) and display the sum for each individual.


for (int i = 0; i < population_size; i++)
{
    int j = 0;
    std::cout << "Organism " << i;
    individual.evaluation = individual.individual[i].at(j) + individual.individual[i].at(j + 1) + individual.individual[i].at(j + 2) + individual.individual[i].at(j + 3) +
        individual.individual[i].at(j + 4) + individual.individual[i].at(j + 5) + individual.individual[i].at(j + 6);

    individual[i].evaluation = individual.evaluation;
}

for (int i = 0; i < population_size; i++)
{
        std::cout << "Evaluation value for individual " << i << " is " << individual[i].evaluation << "\n";
}


std::cout << "\n";
return 0;
}
```

The part where I'm getting errors is here:

```
individual[i].evaluation = individual.evaluation;
```

I thought this would be the way to assign values to the evaluation variable, but it's not. The errors I'm getting are:

Severity    Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
Error   C2676   binary '[': 'one_individual' does not define this operator or a conversion to a type acceptable to the predefined operator  Slow    c:\users\milan\documents\visual studio 2015\projects\slow\slow\slow.cpp 59
Error   C2228   left of '.evaluation' must have class/struct/union  Slow    c:\users\milan\documents\visual studio 2015\projects\slow\slow\slow.cpp 59
Error (active)      no operator "[]" matches these operands Slow    c:\Users\Milan\Documents\Visual Studio 2015\Projects\Slow\Slow\Slow.cpp 59

If anyone could tell me how I would be able to do this or what I should specifically be reading up on to fix this, I'd be very grateful!

Edit: Answered by TobiasR in comments, thanks!

Comment: individual isn't a vector/array/anything which has operator [], so individual[i] makes no sense. You want vector<one_individual> maybe?

Comment: Do you mean renaming my struct to be vector<one_individual>?

Comment: Your identifiers are crazy, you have `individual` vector inside `individual` object of type `one_individual`.

Comment: What I'm trying to do is to have 10 "individuals", where one individual holds a vector filled with some "genes", an evaluation variable and a fit variable. So far I've been able to fill up the genes vector, what I am trying to do now is to evaluate this vector and to fill up the evaluation variable for that "individual" with the value of the sum of the genes.. Hope that makes sense.

Comment: PcAF, you're right. I edited my code now so the struct holds a vector called chromosomes rather than individual, that makes it slightly clearer I think.

Comment: Currently you got 1 individual. Change `one_individual individual;` to `std::Vector<one_individual> individuals` ?

Comment: @TobiasR Took me a few to figure out the rest of the code then needs to change from individual.fit to individuals[i].fit, but no more errors now! Thanks! When I run it now I get some odd error that I've never seen before though, and the program just stops: http://prntscr.com/b02b92 . Judging by google I need to resize, just adding this in case someone stumbles upon this answer and gets the same error.